# Is the process for creating a Pull Request in the case of the monorepo any different from the standard repo case

Tags: github, yarnpkg, pull-request, monorepo

The title completely defines my question (I hope). I am preparing the PR for strapi (https://strapi.com) which is setup as a Yarn Workspace.

Answer (score 0):

As I discovered by various experiments, there is no difference within the context of GotHub